# How do I use appendOnSendAsync?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to use the appendOnSendAsync API call for the Outlook Javascript API. Here is the link for it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#appendonsendasync-data--options--callback-). I've fulfilled all of the requirements needed to use this API such as being in preview and adding the Extended Permissions node in the manifest. I am using this API call on an OnSend event and getting this error: "Extended Permission missing from API call".

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" 
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>a5afbf03-dcfc-435c-8a7b-02f37f162796</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="No-Framework"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.8"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>true</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"         
    xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" 
    xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">

  <Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
      <DesktopFormFactor>
        <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
        <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
          <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="action" />
        </ExtensionPoint>
      </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
  </Hosts>

  <Resources>
    <bt:Urls>
      <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
    </bt:Urls>
    <bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
      <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
    </bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:LongStrings>
      <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      <bt:String id="AppendOnSend" DefaultValue="AppendOnSend"/>
    </bt:LongStrings>
  </Resources>
  <ExtendedPermissions>
    <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
  </ExtendedPermissions>
</VersionOverrides>
```

My Outlook version is: Version 2006 (Build 12914.20000) Office Insider

Comment: Hello Harsh, we recently  published quite a detailed guide here, it should work on your build: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/append-on-send?tabs=windows

Comment: btw can you also share what Exchange server you are connecting to? is this OnPrem 2130, 2016, 2019 or Exchange Online?

Comment: also i noticed you did not closed on of the </VersionOverrides> ? is that a full copy of your manifest?

Comment: @ Juan Balmori , What versions of Exchange On-Prem are supported for appendOnSendAsync? We have a 365 subscription and our Outlook clients are 365 Pro Plus ver. 16.0.12527.21096 64 bit. Our Exchange on-prem is 2016 CU16 (Build 1979.3). We won't be going to Exchange Online for another year or two so hoping this will work for us. Thanks